# Load vertices from file

Tags: android, file-io, opengl-es

I want to load vertices from some sort of file and draw the object . how can I do this for a simple rectangle for example ? I want to start with something simple first. is there any tutorial for doing this that I can refer to ?

Comment: what is your question : loading data from a file or drawing ? Your title says load but your text includes "draw for a rectangle"

Comment: I want to load the positions from a file and draw that

Comment: Load from an Asset but for drawing, I'll pass.

Comment: Your questions boils down to: how do i load float arrays from a file? I'm absolutely sure that a simple google search will help you. You can also refer to this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204363/is-there-a-way-to-import-a-3d-model-into-android) which is similar to yours.

Comment: I'm new to opengl and android and I searched a lot but could not find any good tutorial or simple example .

Comment: so [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and why didn't it work out?